# Angular 8: Automatically check checkbox when a condition is matched

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox

I'm working in a side panel filter for my page, I have the parent checkbox (Select all) and the children checkboxes(specific filters).

Here is what I want, if I select a children I want the parent checkbox to be partially checked, see image below:

[link to example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOtjj.png)

Currently this is my code, my parent checkbox ngModel is set to "dataSource.data.length == selectedAssetTypeFilters.length"

```html
<mat-panel-title>

<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="dataSource.data.length == selectedAssetTypeFilters.length" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="onSelectAll($event, 'assettype')" title="Select All">Data Asset Type</mat-checkbox> </mat-panel-title> </mat-expansion-panel-header>

<div class="filter-content">

<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">

<!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->

<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>

<li class="mat-tree-node">

<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="node.checked" (change)="onFilterUpdate(node, 'assettype');" title="{{node.label}}">
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `[indeterminate]` property of the mat checkbox and bind it with a variable which would go true when at least one child is selected and would go false when all children are selected.

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="node.checked" [intermediate]="childChecked"(change)="onFilterUpdate(node, 'assettype');" title="{{node.label}}">
```

https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview#check-indeterminate

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you do not want to use two way binding on the parent checkbox since the condition you're passing in is a comparison expression, rather than a variable that can be set.

- One-way bind [checked] to the parent checkbox to set its checked state when all items are selected in the list (replace [(ngModel)] binding in your example)
- One-way bind [indeterminate] to the same checkbox, with the bound condition being `dataSource.data.length <= selectedAssetTypeFilters.length && dataSource.data.length > 0` (good to extract this to a getter to keep the template clean)
- Keep the (change) event listener on the parent checkbox to select/deselect all based on its value once clicked.